# $f\equiv c$ a.e. and $x_0$ a lebesgue point$\implies f(x)\equiv f(x_0)$

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading a proof in which I think it is used that if a function $f$ on an interval $I$ is constant almost everywhere, and if $x_0$ is a Lebesgue point, then $f(x)\equiv f(x_0)$ almost everywhere. I was wondering if the following reasonning is okay : suppose $f(x)\equiv c$ a.e. , by definition of a Lebesgue point, $$f(x_0)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{[x_0,x_0+h]}\underbrace{f(x)}_{=c}dx=h\frac{c}{h}=c$$

Comment: That looks reasonable to me.